# C: Julian day library - How do I get a date (ie. yyyy/mm/dd) from a date offset (number of days since X)?

Tags: c, date

I'm looking for a way in C to determine a date from a date offset (ie. number of days since December 31, 1899). For example, `void get_date(const struct date start_date, int offset);`. Basically, a simple library with a `date` struct (but no support for time). It should handle leap years and date-specific things, but nothing related to time (for example, leap seconds and other complications).

```
struct date start_date = {
    .date_day = 31,    // 31
    .date_month = 12,  // December
    .date_year = 1899, // 1899
};

/* From and including: December 31, 1899
 * To, but not including : December 8, 2010
 * It's 40,519 days from the start date to the end date,
 * but not including the end date: [start_date, end_date)  */
get_date(start_date, 40519); // Prints something like "2010-12-08".
```

Ideally, the library should support [Julian days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), potentially going back to epoch January 1, 4713 BC.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with standard C (since you only care about dates, you don't have to worry about the timezone headaches that come with these functions).  This assumes the POSIX definition of time_t, but AFAIK there is no currently-in-use OS with a different definition.

```
#include <time.h>

/* before calling, memset() the 'struct tm' argument to 
   all-bits-zero, set tm_hour to 12, then fill in the
   tm_year, tm_mon, and tm_mday fields; on return, pay
   attention to those fields only. */
struct tm
add_days(const struct tm *base, long days)
{
    time_t t = mktime(base);
    t += 3600*24*days;

    return *localtime(&t);
}
```

Comment: Sure it will; POSIX time_t is signed.

Comment: @Galois: 1800s should work.  @Zack: Doesn't this have potential problems if the days added cross a DST change?

Comment: @Galois: In POSIX, negative time_t values are to be interpreted  according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar. That is well-defined all the way back to CE 1, but can cause a mismatch with historical dates recorded prior to the country-of-recording's switch from Julian to Gregorian. If you've never heard of the proleptic Gregorian calendar, you *probably* don't need to worry about it. @ephemient: That's why part of the setup is setting tm_hour to 12 (noon), safely away from a day boundary.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Timeline has a nice chart of countries' switches from Julian to Gregorian calendars, from which you can work out if any of your dates in the 1800s are going to be troublesome.

Comment: If `time_t` is signed 32 bits (which is allowed in POSIX, and common on 32 bit platforms), then it only goes back 68 years prior to the epoch.

Comment: Hmm, `date -d@$((-2**31))` says `Fri Dec 13 20:45:52 UTC 1901` here.  So I guess I was wrong and caf is right, for 32-bit platforms at least.  But 64-bit platforms (and some 32-bit ones too) tend to use 64-bit `time_t`, which covers pretty much everything.

Comment: I haven't had to use a machine with a 32-bit `time_t` in ... five years now?  S'true, though, 32-bit only goes back to 1901.